# how to execute SURF algorithm in multi-thread?

Tags: opencv

I am working on OpenCV by using **SURF** algorithm. The current bottleneck is the calculating speed of two functions: **surf.detect and surf.compute**.(about 100ms) while the idea request is under 40ms.

I am wondering which function inside the whole open source to revise so those two functions can be executed in multi-thread model. ( One possible resolution I guess is to implement openMP on for loop )

Comment: [SURF](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cpp) is already implemented in parallel. You may want to use the [CUDA version](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/surf.cuda.cpp)

Comment: Thank you Miki ! Is there any readMe of how to use this CUDA version?

Comment: Never did it so I'm not 100% sure, but I think you need to rebuild OpenCV (+ contrib modules) with CUDA support, and then call the SURF in cuda namespace

Comment: Thank you for the advice and I will try it.